# $\ell_p$-strictly singular operators and non-$\ell_p$-factoring operators

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-ideals

Let $X,Y,E$ be Banach spaces.  We say that a continuous linear operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is $E$-strictly singular, and write $T\in\mathcal{SS}_E(X,Y)$, whenever it fails to fix a copy of $E$.  More precisely, $T\in\mathcal{SS}_E(X,Y)$ whenever for each closed subspace $U\subseteq X$ satisfying $U\approx E$, the operator $T$ is not bounded below on $U$, i.e. for $\epsilon>0$ there is $u\in U$ such that $\|Tu\|<\epsilon\|u\|$.

We say that $T$ is non-$E$-factoring, and write $T\in\mathcal{M}_{\ell_p}(X,Y)$, whenever $Id_E$ fails to factor through $T$, i.e. whenever there are no $A\in\mathcal{L}(E,X)$ and $B\in\mathcal{L}(Y,E)$ such that $BTA=Id_E$, where $I_E\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ is the identity operator on $E$.

It is clear that we always have $\mathcal{SS}_E(X,Y)\subseteq\mathcal{M}_E(X,Y)$.  I believe (but have not yet checked to be sure) that these classes coincide whenever $E=\ell_1$ or $E=c_0$.  If $1<p<\infty$, we also have $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_p}(L_p)=\mathcal{M}_{\ell_p}(L_p)$ and $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_2}(L_p)=\mathcal{M}_{\ell_2}(L_p)$.

**Question 1.**  Let $1<p<\infty$.  Do there exist Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_p}(X,Y)\neq\mathcal{M}_{\ell_p}(X,Y)$?

It is known that $\mathcal{SS}_{c_0}$ and $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_p}$ are norm-closed operator ideals for $1\leq p<\infty$.  I believe (but have not checked) that the same is true for $\mathcal{M}_{c_0}$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\ell_1}$.  I believe (but have not checked) that $\mathcal{M}_{\ell_p}$ is also an operator ideal in the sense of Pietsch for $1<p<\infty$, but I do not know whether it is norm-closed.

**Question 2.**  Let $1<p<\infty$.  Do there exist Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $\mathcal{M}_{\ell_p}(X,Y)$ fails to be norm-closed in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ (in the operator norm)?

An example satisfying Q2 would also satisfy Q1.

One last thing:  Are there references for any of the "known" facts I mentioned above?  For example, where is it proved that $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_p}$ is a norm-closed operator ideal?

Thanks guys!

Comment: For Question 1, cannot you just take $X$ to be $\ell_p$ and $Y$ to be a Banach space containing a copy of $\ell_p$, but no complemented copy of $\ell_p$? For example, take $Y=C[0,1]$. Letting $T$ be an isomorphic embedding of $\ell_p$ into $C[0,1]$, we obviously have $T\notin \mathcal{S}\mathcal{S}_{\ell_p}$. Moreover $T\in \mathcal{M}_{\ell_p}$ since $I_{\ell_p}$ cannot factor through $C[0,1]$, and therefore cannot factor through $T$. But maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Further to my comment above, if $U: \ell_p\longrightarrow C[0,1]$ and $V:C[0,1]\longrightarrow \ell_p$ were such that $VU=I_{\ell_p}$, then we would have that $UVUV=UV$ is a projection on $C[0,1]$. I think straightforward arguments (which you should be able to write down, though I think I have seen them set out in a paper of Laustsen) show that the range of $UV$ must be isomorphic to $\ell_p$. But this is impossible, so no such $U$ and $V$ exist in the first place.

Comment: @PhilipBrooker cool thank you!

Comment: No worries, Ben. The paper of Laustsen is (though there may be other references) is *Maximal ideals in the algebra of operators on certain Banach spaces*, published in the Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society. See in particular Lemma 3.6 of that paper.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is still open whether $\mathscr{M}_{\ell_p}$ is closed under addition, hence it is not clear whether is coincides with $\mathscr{S\!\!S}_{\ell_p}$.

That $\mathscr{S\!\!S}_{c_0(\Gamma)}$ is a closed operator ideal (for any set $\Gamma$) is not too hard to show. See Proposition 3.13 in

> W. B. Johnson, T. Kania and G. Schechtman, [Closed ideals of operators on and complemented subspaces of Banach spaces of functions with countable support](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2016-144-10/S0002-9939-2016-13084-0/), 
>   *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **144** (2016), 4471-4485.

That $\mathscr{S\!\!S}_E$ is a closed operator ideal for a minimal space $E$ follows from a variation of Kato's lemma; see Proposition 2.5 in

> T. Kania and N. J. Laustsen, Uniqueness of the maximal ideal of operators on the $\ell_p$-sum of $\ell_\infty^n$ ($n\in \mathbb N$) for $1<p<\infty$, *Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc.* **160** (2016) 413-421.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_p}$ is a closed ideal is claimed without proof in 1.18 of "Operator Ideals" (p445, ch11 in Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces). Also, why do you like mathscr when it is so hard to read? And why do you dislike mathcal so much?

Comment: Also, isn't the fact that $\mathcal{SS}_{\ell_p}$ is a closed operator ideal an immediate consequence of Prop 2.5 in your preprint "Uniqueness of the maximal ideal..." mentioned above? (You call it prop 3.5 for some reason, I guess it was re-numbered in the published version.)

Comment: @BenWallis, that right. I keep confusing the symbols $\mathscr{M}_E$ and $\mathscr{S}_E$.